# pass in fstream where ifstream expected

Tags: c++, casting

```
void foo(ifstream &ifs)
{
    //do something
}

int main()
{
    fstream fs("a.txt", fstream::in);
    foo(fs); //error, can't compile
}
```

The above code can't compile, seems like I can't initialize an `ifstream &` with a `fstream` object? What if I do it this way:

```
foo(static_cast<ifstream>(fs));
```

or

```
foo(dynamic_cast<ifstream>(fs));
```

Comment: For a start, they're unrelated types.

Comment: ifstream does not extrend fstream.  Both fstream and ifstream extend istream, but other than that, as Oli said, they're unrelated.

Comment: @Corbin, holy, I thought `ifstream` and `ofstream` are derived from `fstream`.

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of odd, but I guess they decided to go with fstream instead of iofstream :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you want foo() to take istream.  As indicated in the comments, this is a base type for both ifstream and fstream.

```
void foo( istream & is )
```

There is a nice reference for these classes at cplusplus.com:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream "Input stream"
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream "Input file stream class"
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream "Input/output file stream class"